# Two different hex values for a solid colour

Tags: shaders

does anyone know the solution to this?

I am trying to create a solid colour image for AI but blender seems to create two hex values for the same colour. I have used the lighter blue as an example Examples below:

[image]

[image]

Cheers

Comment: How do you create this image? If it's a 3D render, the light source might be closer to one side of the image than the other.

Comment: No light sources, the world shader is set to white and strength of 1 to eliminate all shadows. The point of an image like this is to create a solid colour that the AI can read it but blender is creating two hex values for each solid colour.

Comment: likely dithering (assuming that the two colors are sampled from the image in slightly different spots)

Comment: Legend! thankyou, setting dither to 0.00 in post-processing fixed the issue. Many thanks